# Replicator Neural Network for outlier detection, Step-wise function causing same prediction

Tags: neural-network, outliers

In my project, one of my objectives is to find outliers in aeronautical engine data and chose to use the Replicator Neural Network to do so and read the following report on it (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.12.3366&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and am having a slight understanding issue with the step-wise function (page 4, figure 3) and the prediction values due to it.

The explanation of a replicator neural network is best described in the above report but as a background the replicator neural network I have built works by having the same number of outputs as inputs and having 3 hidden layers with the following activation functions:

Hidden layer 1 = tanh sigmoid S1(θ) = tanh,
Hidden layer 2 = step-wise, S2(θ) = 1/2 + 1/(2(k − 1)) {summation each variable j} tanh[a3(θ −j/N)]
Hidden Layer 3 = tanh sigmoid S1(θ) = tanh,
Output Layer 4 = normal sigmoid S3(θ) = 1/1+e^-θ
I have implemented the algorithm and it seems to be training (since the mean squared error decreases steadily during training). The only thing I don't understand is how the predictions are made when the middle layer with the step-wise activation function is applied since it causes the 3 middle nodes' activations to be become specific discrete values (e.g. my last activations on the 3 middle were 1.0, -1.0, 2.0 ) , this causes these values to be forward propagated and me getting very similar or exactly the same predictions every time.

The section in the report on page 3-4 best describes the algorithm but i have no idea what i have to do to fix this, i don't have much time either :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the problem of implementing this algorithm and here is my insight into the problem that you might have had: The middle layer, by utilizing a step-wise function, is essentially performing clustering on the data. Each layer transforms the data into a discrete number which could be interpreted as a coordinate in a grid system. Imagine we use two neurons in the middle layer with step-wise values ranging from -2 to +2 in increments of 1. This way we define a 5x5 grid where each set of features will be placed. The more steps you allow, the more grids. The more grids, the more "clusters" you have.

This all sounds good and all. After all, we are compressing the data into a smaller (dimensional) representation which then is used to try to reconstruct into the original input.

This step-wise function, however, has a big problem on itself: back-propagation does not work (in theory) with step-wise functions. You can find more about this in [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220869715_Replicator_Neural_Networks_for_Outlier_Modeling_in_Segmental_Speech_Recognition). In this last paper they suggest switching the step-wise function with a ramp-like function. That is, to have almost an infinite amount of clusters.

Your problem might be directly related to this. Try switching the step-wise function with a ramp-wise one and measure how the error changes throughout the learning phase.

By the way, do you have any of this code available anywhere for other researchers to use?

Comment: Wow, I'm so sorry for the long reply! and the ramp function makes a lot of sense as I back track to the problem and thank you also.

Comment: (Accidentally pressed enter), 

What i will do is aim to dig up the code that I wrote.  I basically created an all purpose neural network program in C++ where you could specify the layers and nodes, It was on my old hard drive which was a pain to use at the time but i will aim to find it and post it online for any other researchers when i get a chance.